# Updating Date & Time into MySQL via python

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to update my date & time columns in my MySQLdb database. I have 2 columns by the name date1 and time1 and both are type TEXT. This is my python code

```
import MySQLdb
import datetime

db = MySQLdb.connect('localhost','admin','admin','dbname')
cur = db.cursor()

a = datetime.datetime.strftime(datetime.date.today(),'%Y-%m-%d'))
cur.execute('update Data set date1={0}'.format(a))
db.commit()
```

But after this code executes I see the value in the column set as '2000'.

I tried several datetypes in MySQL - varchar2, date, datetime but they always show as '2000' or '0000-00-00'.

When I run this sql query directly it works fine:

```
UPDATE `Data` SET `date1`='22-04-1994'
```

I googled this error and tried this:

```
a = datetime.date.today()
a = a.isoformat()
```

But it shows in the database as 2000.

Edit:
I tried using {0} instead of +a. Still coming as 2000.

I am using Mysql version 5.5.51-38.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think what your query does, since you concatenate strings. You can even print it out. Since you don't put the date into quotes it will be considered a calculation. So you're saying:

```
date1=2016-11-5
```

This is of course 2000, but you want

```
date1='2016-11-5'
```

The best way is to use parameters so the underlying system is doing all this for you rather than you concatenating strings and trying to escape them correctly.

Comment: But the variable type is either way a string. I even tried using str(a) to convert to a complete string type but no luck there also.

Comment: @user2726634 *variable* is a string, but you do see the difference in the cases I've shown? Even in your own manual example you have quotes, why not in the actual one?

Comment: You are right. I did not understand initially. But now it worked!

Answer (score 2):

You should be using parameters.  But, if not, you need to include single quotes around date constants:

```
cur.update('update Data set date1 = '{0}'".format(a))
```